# Is there a Django "app" that can manage your users' profiles?

Tags: python, django, profile, pinax

"My Profile", notification options, settings

...The checkbox stuff...

I'm familiar with Pinax, but is there a specific app that manages **just profiles and accounts**?

I don't want the other heavy stuff associated with social networking...I only want the profile account management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is django-profiles:

http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

Another one, I haven't used either this or the one Mike posted, so caveat emptor. (What's Latin for 'downloader'? ;)

http://code.google.com/p/django-profile/